# Liveness probe failed: Get-http context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, livenessprobe

After a DO update to 1.24.16-do.0 , my cloud-config pod encountered  Liveness probe failed: Get-<http.ip> context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
When i curl the ip, i'm getting a 137 error, as the pod is backing off i suppose.
The traffic is very less and the memory/cpu/threads is much beyond limits thresholds. The issue is reproduced on different cluster compute nodes.
Any other resources were also not changed during the update.
deployment of my liveness-probe

```
http-get http://:8888/actuator/health delay=180s
```

the image is being pulled by an internal registry and works, too. I also tried to disable all the components that being checked as part of the actuator health check, but nothing has changed.
liveness config:

```
livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 4
      httpGet:
        path: /actuator/health
        port: 8080
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 180
      periodSeconds: 15
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
```

i'd be gratefule for any hint

Comment: Care to share your yaml configuration for the pod? specially the liveness/readiness section

Comment: @DanF i edited my inital question

Comment: hmm can you try giving it more cpu resources? and increase timeoutSeconds to something like 15secs

Comment: yeah, i will try your approach and hope it solves this thing

Comment: Well @DanF it seems, the new DO Update messes all the resources (limits) up, so there is no other way than deleting these or temporarily don't use them until digital-ocean fixes this asap.

Answer (score 2):

You encountered the error: *"Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers"*, which means that the probe was considered to be failed by the Kubernetes as it didn't responded in specified time.

You need to increase your timeoutSeconds to 10s for livenessProbe.

**timeoutSeconds**: This parameter is part of the configuration for both liveness and readiness probes. It specifies the number of seconds after which the probe times out. The default value is 1 second. If a probe doesn’t respond within the specified timeoutSeconds, Kubernetes considers the probe to have failed.